# How to get message information from discord bot through websocket and webhook

Tags: javascript, websocket, discord.js, bots

So I currently am able to receive messages from a discord channel and post them with a webhook, but when I get information sent by a bot I receive @deleted-role when I'm trying to get information from one of my discord servers and post it into another.

I currently have this code to send the information retrieved from the JSON data array received from the API:

```
if (d.author != null) {
        if (d.channel_id === testchannel) {
            if (d.attachments) {
              let client = new WebhookClient({ url: "https://ptb.discord.com/api/webhooks/MY WEBHOOK" });
          
              if (d.content){
                let content = d.content ? d.content : { embeds: d.embeds };
                client.send(content);
              }
              for (let i = 0; i < d.attachments.length; i++) {
                let image = d.attachments[i].url;
                client.send(image);
              }
            }
            else {
                let content = d.content ? d.content : { embeds: d.embeds };
                let client = new WebhookClient({ url: "https://ptb.discord.com/api/webhooks/MY WEBHOOK" })

                client.send(content);

            }
        }
```

Let me know if you need anymore information on this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can understand your issue. Do you expect the same role to be available on both servers?

Comment: No, I expect to see an actual response not just "Deleted-Role". Normally when I post the contents, it'll have the actual contents of the message, but when a BOT sends a message, all I get is "Deleted-Role" as the message response. I want to know how to get the actual information that the bot is posting like I would if a normal person would post something.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out why I was getting only Deleted_Role. My embeds weren't working properly. I just spliced out deleted role from the content I received. Closing this out.